# Finding chromatic polynomials of graphs in two ways?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Find the chromatic polynomial $c_{G}(k)$ by:

1. relation $c_{G}(k) = c_{G−e}(k) − c_{G/e}(k)$
2. principle of inclusion and exclusion.

The graph looks like a triangle of vertices a (top), b (right) , and d (bottom) all connected to one another. Then vertex c is connected to vertex b. And that's it. Basically a triangle with added edge connected to one vertex of the triangle.

This is graph theory and combinatorics.Please help how to solve this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With deletion-contraction, I would be clever about this: $c_{G}(k) = c_{G - bd}(k) - c_{G/bd}(k)$. So if we remove $bd$, we have a path on four vertices. And so, it is a tree with chromatic polynomial $k(k-1)^{3}$. Similarly, we contract the edge $bd$ to get a path on $3$ vertices, giving us the chromatic polynomial $k(k-1)^{2}$. And so $c_{G}(k) = k(k-1)^{2}(k-2)$.

I'm not familiar with the inclusion-exclusion approach. Perhaps someone who is can offer some advice on that end.

Comment: Inclusion/exclusion approach has something to do with the formula: N_0 = N - Sum N *(a_i) + Sum N * (a_i * a_j) - Sum N * (a_i*a_j*a_k)

Comment: If you could use LaTeX formatting, that would be helpful. The site has instructions around on how to use the LaTeX formatting. :-)

Also, you will have to better define the terms being added and what they represent.

Comment: This is the fastest way I could do it with it kinda looking decent : N_0 = N - ∑ N(a_i) + ∑ N *(a_i * a_j) - ∑ N*(a_i*a_j*a_k). It says for example, for the graph K_3, the graph has 3 edges so we take r=3. Computing N(a_1) = N(a_2) = N(a_3) = x^2, since every coloring satisfying one of the properties has two vertices with the same color, and the third vertex may be any color. Also, N(a_1a_2) = N(a_2a_3) = N(a_1a_3) = N(a_1a_2a_3) = x, as

Comment: We are in general happy to help, but please do take the time to learn how to use the site. It makes our lives easier. Also, your formula looks like the general inclusion-exclusion formula. I'm familiar with inclusion-exclusion, but just not how to apply it here. So I can't really help you except to clarify the approach I already showed.

Here is a link to the LaTeX reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Sorry, yes it basically is